# Does a year of entrepreneurship in an unrelated field affect an MS application?

Tags: masters, computer-science

I did my Bachelors in computer science. I have been working for 1.5 years in a reputed software firm **working on distributed systems**, information retrieval and such fields.

I want to apply for MS in CSE (distributed systems or ML) next year but before that I want to **start my game development company** which has been a dream. It might also help me earn a lot of money which I will need to study further. **Game development is largely software engineering, but has nothing to do with distributed systems or ML.** If my game development start-up fails I will happily do the MS right away.

Will switching from my current "related" job to a somewhat unrelated field trigger an alarm? Am I at a risk of getting rejected?

How can I patch things up if I have to after my game development gig?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting that you do not necessarily need to self-finance your graduate study.  A teaching assistantship would take care of your tuition and would give you a stipend to live on (frugally).  Teaching assistantships are not hard to come by in the field of CS -- as compared to some other fields, because universities generally need a fleet of TAs to grade and/or teach the undergraduate classes.

You may want to consider putting in some applications for grad school this coming December - January.  You can always quit your current job after collecting a strong recommendation from your current supervisor.  Then you would have February - August to try out your entrepreneurial idea and see how it goes.  If it's taking off and you're really enjoying it, you can always cancel (or possibly postpone) the grad school plans.

Comment: I disagree with "Teaching assistantships are not hard to come by in the field of CS." For _masters_ students in CS, funding (by way of TA and/or RA positions) can be very hard to come by. In my school, for example, there are _far_ more masters students that want such positions than there are positions available.

Comment: @ff524 - (a) I was comparing with some other fields; (b) there are departments which don't make a hard distinction between PhD students and masters students.

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your post to clarify what you meant, then. As a general statement without further details, "Teaching assistantships are not hard to come by in the field of CS" is a rather misleading statement.

Comment: thanks for the answer. however it doesn't answer the core of the question. Will my game dev attempt spoil my chances of a good MS?

I plan to apply the year **after** this because I need some time to try out my own company. 6 months is no good. It will be a half assed attempted :)

Comment: If six months is not enough for you to get a sense of whether your project is going to be successful, or whether you enjoy it, then you do indeed have a dilemma.

Comment: @aparente001 For me, to make a polished game it would take 3 months easily. After that there will be marketing stuff, etc. There is no way I can stop at one game.

anyway I agree to disagree with you in this aspect. If I do end up spending a full year on my start-up will I have problems with my MS application?

Comment: If your entrepreneurial experience turns out to be something you do not want to put on your resume, you can say you took a gap year and be rather vague.  I believe there is an advantage to going straight to grad school, but it's not do or die.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks. but I am not ashamed of putting it on my resume. But the question is, should I be? Started game dev company vs took a break year?

Comment: If you are proud of something you have done, mention it.  If you are not proud of the thing you did, skip over it or leave it rather blurry.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for your patience :) but my primary concern is not how well my start-up does. If it does well, I wouldn't even apply. But my concern whether my interest in a subject different from core computer science is a red flag for them.

Comment: I studied at UW-Madison which encourages people who have worked in the field to apply -- which makes sense to me, because when you work in the real world you get *perspective*.